# Next Export fails when using appdir - "PageNotFoundError: Cannot find module for page /(...)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, next.js

I'm using NextJS with the experimental appDir flag, I've added my pages like so:

[image]

Where layout.tsx on root and onboard look like:

```
export default function DefaultLayout({ children }) {
    return (
        <>
            {children}
        </>
    )
}
```

and the onboarding page looks like:

```
export default function Onboard() {
    return <div>onboarding page</div>
}
```

This works fine in the browser when I hit localhost:3000/public/onboard - however when attempting to do a next build I get the error:

```
PageNotFoundError: Cannot find module for page: /public/onboard
    at Object.getPagePath (...)
```

Not sure if this has to do with appDir next build being sunupported?

Comment: Do you get the error on build or export?

Comment: @VinodDalvi it's actually on export.

Comment: It's not possible yet. https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/app-directory-roadmap

Answer (score 1):

It's available on the nextjs@canary now. It was released yesterday

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases

Docs: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/configuring/static-export